# Adding to CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to keep adding to a CSS grid, but do not want to keep re-numbering the CSS. Does anyone have any suggestions to simplify this code?

```
.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.div2 { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.div3 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
.div4 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.div5 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; }
.div6 { grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4; }
.div7 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2; }
.div8 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3; }
.div9 { grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4; }
.div10 { grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2; }
.div11 { grid-area: 4 / 2 / 5 / 3; }
.div12 { grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 4; }
.div13 { grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 2; }
.div14 { grid-area: 5 / 2 / 6 / 3; }
.div15 { grid-area: 5 / 3/ 6 / 4; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item">15</div>
</div>
```